# Javascript script doesn't load in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Breakout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <canvas width="900" height="450" class="canvas"></canvas>

    <script src="scripts/base.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the index file

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.canvas{
  background-color: #b7b7b7;
}
```

This is the CSS file

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();

context.drawRect(20,30,50,40);
context.fillStyle("#0022ff");
context.fill();

context.endPath();
```

And the javascript file.
I am trying to create a breakout game and I am following a tutorial from udemy. Unfortunately, it seems there is something wrong with this code, but I don't know what. I verified the code one thousand times and I haven't found anything.

Comment: Try `var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');`

Comment: Or `var canvas = document.querySelector( '.canvas' );`

Comment: @hungerstar +1, but don't forget to mention: In case of multiple `.canvas` it's better to use `querySelectorAll`

Comment: True, with `querySelectorAll()` you get a NodeList and need to use `canvas[ 0 ]` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `var context = canvas.getContext('2d');` should be `var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');` because you're using `document.getElementsByClassName` which will return a collection of all the elements with that class name. and you want the context of the first one.
- `context.drawRect` should be `context.rect`.
- `context.fillStyle` is not a function it should be `context.fillStyle = "#0022ff";`
- `context.endPath();` should be `context.closePath();`
- In your case you don't need `context.beginPath();` and `context.closePath();`. `context.rect` already creates the path.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas');
var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');


context.rect(20, 30, 50, 40);
context.fillStyle = "#0022ff";
context.fill();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.canvas {
  background-color: #b7b7b7;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="900" height="450" class="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you. I realised that i used the fillStyle as a method. That was the problem

Comment: There are few issues I listed them out.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

That's because in your `var canvas`, you're calling `document.getElementByClassName` which will return an "[array-like" object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). So, I'd suggest you to use IDs instead of selecting using a class.

Comment: Nothing wrong with selecting by class name, just depends on the method used. `getElementByClassName()` returns an _array-like_ object as you said, `querySelector()` will return the first element with the specified selector, in this case, `.canvas`. But yeah, if you want to target a single element and don't want to take chances, then an ID is a great choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use fillRect instead of drawRect:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillRect(20,30,50,40);
ctx.endPath();


</script>
```